# How to manage different versions of XSD generated classes?

Tags: c#, xsd

**Context**

We are developing a software for our Government, the government releases some PDF's describing an XML file structure and their respective XSD. So, we generate all the classes we will need from the XSD and everything is going well.

**Problem**

The problem is that the Government releases too many versions of the same XSD and our software will need to handle all the different versions.
All the versions are very similar, but little different. Some fields are added, others excluded, some string support four characters in one version and just three in others and so on.

My question is how to design my software to handle all the different versions simultaneously and avoiding code duplication?

**Current solution**

For now I am creating each version in their specific namespace, this way, I can instantiate a specific version given a parameter. The problem (if it is a problem) is that I see that I will have too much code duplication between the namespaces. Is there a better way or a design pattern to help me solve this problem?

Comment: Let all the bare, xsd generated classes (which should be `partial`!) implement the same interfaces, so the higher layers don't need repetition. For the things that *have* to be separate below the interface layer, but only slightly differ, you might want to look into [T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb126445.aspx). Also, [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) are your friend!

Comment: Nothing like a standard that's non standard...

Comment: ["The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from"](https://xkcd.com/927/)